# ms access 2000: Too few parameters with DSum

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this problem for like an hour now and I just can't find the solution through Google, so maybe someone here can help me?
I have this table here:

```
|--------------------------|
|          Table1          |
| Product | Amount | Buyer |
|--------------------------|
|    Food |      4 |     1 |
|   Paper |     30 |     1 |
|    Food |      2 |     2 |
|--------------------------|
```

And I want to have this table here:

```
|-------------------|
|       table2      |
| Buyer | Purchases |
|-------------------|
|     1 |        34 |
|     2 |         2 |
|-------------------|
```

Before the code is executed, table2 looks like this:

```
|-------------------|
|       table2      |
| Buyer | Purchases |
|-------------------|
|     1 |           |
|     2 |           |
|-------------------|
```

The code I tried is:

```
UPDATE table2
SET Purchases = (
  DSum("Amount", "table1", "table1.Buyer = " & table2.Buyer)
)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Too few parameters. Expected 1
```

If I remove the last part of the DSum method:

```
UPDATE table2
SET Purchases = (
  DSum("Amount", "table1")
)
```

I don't get an error. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you're going wrong with a table or field name or type. Are these the actual names you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the table names:

```sql
UPDATE 
    table2
SET 
    Purchases = DSum("Amount", "table1", "Buyer = " & Buyer & "")
```

No single quotes as Buyer is a number.

Comment: Buyer is a number in the sample data, and while there's no reason to include the table name, there's no reason it should do harm either.

Comment: @ErikA: One can't be sure ... all sample fields are right justified.

Comment: The `& ""` at the end is superfluous.

Comment: @SunKnight0: No. It signals the end of the string expression and that you deliberately have no quotes around the variable.

Comment: Strange. It should not influence the operation, only the readability.